# Make *.apib files load into IntelliJ Markdown plug-in

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, markdown

How can I tell IntelliJ (or its Markdown or Multimarkdown plug-in) that files named *.apib are Markdown, and should be handled the same way as files named *.md?

I found the Preferences for the plugins (Preferences: Other Settings: Markdown/MultiMarkdown), but these only control what it means to "be handled the same way," not how to get there in the first place.

I also found Preferences: Plugins, but it only seems to handle installing the plugins, not configuring them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Preferences and choose Editor. Select File Types and select Markdown Language, then add *.apib to the list of patterns.